# Woocommerce hook after creating order?

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I am looking for a hook which will be triggered after someone submit checkout form and order placed ( no matter he made the payment or not ) .

I tried [`woocommerce_new_order`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_new_order/)

But it's not working.

Comment: Post your code that's not working.

Comment: `function action_woocommerce_new_order( $order_id ) {

 update_option('new_order', $order_id );
};
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1 );`

Comment: `'woocommerce_new_order'` hook is the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution. An old order already exists in my order list. So when I am adding new items in order, woocommerce just updating my old unpaid order. So I use `woocommerce_resume_order` action too. Now it's fine.

Answer (score 14):

Try `woocommerce_thankyou` hook. This will trigger after recieving order successfully, no matter how user made payment.

```
$hook_to = 'woocommerce_thankyou';
$what_to_hook = 'wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething';
$prioriy = 111;
$num_of_arg = 1;    
add_action($hook_to, $what_to_hook, $prioriy, $num_of_arg);

function wl8OrderPlacedTriggerSomething($order_id){
      //do something...
}
```

For more reference dig into ***woocommerce/templates/checkout/thankyou.php***

Comment: Note: this event will be triggered again if the end user refreshes the thank you page for whatever reason.

Comment: Is there a hook that only works on save?

Comment: also note this hook will *not* be triggered if  a user somehow skips the thankyou page