# Filter hook before create order WooCommerce

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I would like to write a little script that does a check whenever an order is created in WooCommerce (right after checkout) and then conditionally changes the Shipping Address of the customer.

I think I need a filter hook that 'fires' as soon as an order is created. I tried several things in the [WooCommerce Hook reference guide](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html), like: 'woocommerce_create_order', but without success. I also contacted WooCommerce support, but no solution. I also checked out: [Woocommerce hook after order (on Stackexchange)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212400/woocommerce-hook-after-creating-order), however I would need a filter hook that fires before order create (not after).

What I would like to accomplish is something like:

```
function alter_shipping ($order) {
  if ($something == $condition) {
    $order->shipping_address = "..."; //(simplified)
  }
  return $order;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'alter_shipping', 10, 1 );
```

This filter 'woocommerce_create_order' in above example doesn't pass any variables to be manipulated.

I need to conditionally manipulate the shipping address in a WooCommerce order as it gets created. Does anyone know a suitable filter hook for this? Or another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stumbled on this looking for the same thing which I've now figured out (Woocommerce 3.x)...

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'mbm_alter_shipping', 10, 1 );
function mbm_alter_shipping ($order) {

  if ($something == $condition) {
    $address = array(
      'first_name' => 'Martin',
      'last_name'  => 'Stevens',
      'company'    => 'MBM Studio',
      'email'      => 'test@test.com',
      'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
      'address_1'  => '99 Arcadia Avenue',
      'address_2'  => '', 
      'city'       => 'London',
      'state'      => '',
      'postcode'   => '12345',
      'country'    => 'UK'
    );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

  }

  return $order;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you got the right filter that arguments are wrong way:

**woocommerce 3.0.6 doc**

```
// define the woocommerce_create_order callback 
function filter_woocommerce_create_order( $null, $instance ) { 
    // make filter magic happen here... 
    return $null; 
}; 

// add the filter 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'filter_woocommerce_create_order', 10, 2 );
```

So your `$order` would always be null, then put the null replace of your `$order`, and let `$order` move to second params. Then return value must be `$order_id` or the try-catch function would stuck your snippets. There is [full doc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#321) of this function.

**fixed**

```
function alter_shipping (null,$order) {
  if ($something == $condition) {
    $order->shipping_address = "..."; //(simplified)
  }
  $order_id = $order->save();

  return $order_id;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_create_order', 'alter_shipping', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try action hook `woocommerce_checkout_create_order`, it is called just before save to DB.

[woocommerce_checkout_create_order](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#334)