# WooCommerce order created via REST - sending the date_created along

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

So as the topic hints, I'm trying to get WooCommerce to accept my `date_created` that I'm sending along with the order I'm creating via REST:

```
POST https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/orders
{
   (order_fields)
   ...

   "date_created": "05-12-2017 13:00:00"
}
```

The field is readonly sadly, so does anyone know if this is possible?

The reason I need this, is the orders are created in an external system, and the dates need to be the same across both systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`date_created`](http://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-properties) is `read-only` value meaning that you cannot set it over the REST API. What you can do is:

1. Send creation time from your "external system" as `order meta data` (sample PHP code below) and then in WooCommerce [trigger the action](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212400/woocommerce-hook-after-creating-order) using custom plug-in which updates order `date_created` according to a meta value.

> ```
> $json_encode['meta_data'][0]['key'] = 'my_date_created';
> $json_encode['meta_data'][0]['value'] = '05-12-2017 13:00:00';
> ```

2. Update `date_created` in your "external system" with `date_created` from jSon returned by Woocommerce in order to have values synchronised.

If you just want to pair order records do it over `order ID` returned in jSon by Woocommerce (Woocommerce returns a jSon when the order was created successfully). You will add `order ID` record to your "external system".

Comment: I'll give you credit for the answer, as I ended up doing something similar.

Comment: 6 years later and this is still a thing. My case is that I am uploading old orders and need to set the date to an older date.
You mind giving a more complete answer, suggesting the Trigger and the language to use?

Comment: @Yoni Direct SQL query is the way.